# Does anybody use Karate DSL as a test data management tool?

Tags: api, testing, karate

i am glad with the use of Karate DSL for API testing. But i was wondering if it is suited for test data generation. Some of our UI tests need some particular data load which I think could be generated by calling the API (Rest and SOAP) through Karate DSL.

Is Karate adequate for this or would you use other specific data generation tool?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you start looking at the new RC version (0.9.9.RC3) you can use a function to [generate data](https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/1343201222396821504): https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop#json-function-data-source

```
* def generator = function(i){ if (i == 20) return null; return { name: 'cat' + i, age: i } }
```